# Take excel sheet value as it is input to java program

Tags: excel

I want excel sheet value as a input for my program, but 24hr time format changed in 12hr format after program run.Example:Excel contains 23:34:10 but when i run program in netbean, output is 11:34:10.I want 23:34:10 as a output.

```
public class DateTime {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

        File f=new File("D:\\BCCIDT.xls");

        Workbook wb=Workbook.getWorkbook(f);
        Sheet s=wb.getSheet(0);

        int row=s.getRows();
        int col=s.getColumns();

       for(int j=0;j<row;j++){
            Cell c=s.getCell(0, j);
            System.out.println(c.getContents()+"\n");

            String msg=c.getContents();

             Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss").parse(msg);
               String newString = new SimpleDateFormat("kk").format(date); 
               System.out.println("Time = " + newString +"\n");
              }
       }
}
```

> Input is-23:00:35  Output-11:00:35

But i want Output-23:00:35

Answer (score 0):

Please check the patterns for [`SimpleDateFormat(..)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html). 
Try `SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss")`

Comment: Thank you sir for answer